# How can I reliably use code from github in vendor/gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, github

I like to vendor as many gems as possible, except those that must be built on each platform (libxml, etc.) but sometimes I like to use some bleeding-edge code rather than the gems that are out there on the gem servers.

Can I clone a github gem directly into vendor/gems. I guess I could, but will it affect my app  code since it is already a git repository? I would like to just do periodic git pulls for these couple of gems so that I don't have to update every gem and maybe break something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use of `vendor/gems` has been deprecated in favor of using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) and `Gemfile` instead. The vendor system had a number of flaws including a lack of support for compiled extensions, so it was never a complete solution.

You're better off locking your versions in the Gemfile as required. If you want to use bleeding edge versions, comment out the version declaration, remove `Gemfile.lock` and do a `bundle install` again.

It's often the case that the published version of the gem has a flaw you need to repair by forking and fixing, so it's easy to track this:

```
gem 'broken-gem', :git => 'git://github.com/myname/broken-gem.git'
```

The advantage here is that the `Gemfile` serves as documentation of what versions of the gems you require, and where to get them. `vendor/gems` leaves people in the dark as to where that version came from.

Comment: Also possibly relevant is the `bundle package` command: http://gembundler.com/bundle_package.html

Comment: All correct with notice: to update a gem do not remove your whole `Gemfile.lock` just run `bundle update <gemname>`. In this way you'll update only that gem and its dependencies leaving other gems fixed to previous versions.